# react native: alter state from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

Parent that import child:

```
    <Component onPress={this.state.value = 5} />
```

Child in another component:

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: '',
  };
}
```

The challenge or restriction is that I can't touch the child component and only have the parent to work with, is there any way to alter or influence the properties, state, or code of the child component without actually touching it? (New to all this sorry)

Comment: Are you sure there is no way for you to influence the props of the child? This is usually how data flow happens in react.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the data when you press the button? If you want to change the data when you press the button, please forward the data.

**Parent**

```js
 <Component val={5} />
```

**Child**

```js
<Button
   title="Press me"
   onPress={() => this.setState({value: this.props.val})}
/>
```